# What causes the error: SQL72007 in a Schema Comparison file?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio

A colleague recently got the following error when attempting to Compare and Update a database with SQL changes using a SQL Schema Comparison (*.scmp) file:

SQL72007: The syntax check failed ‘Incorrect syntax near ?.’ in the batch near:
‘’

This is the very first line in the file.

There were no changes to the SCMP file.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the "Build Action" in the properties of the schema comparison file (.scmp) had gotten changed to "PostDeploy". We have no clue how it changed!

The correct setting is "None".

[image]

This same question was asked 2 years ago [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/sql72007-error-in-schema-comparison-file/1142281), but never answered.